# accessing a variable in another program (c++)

Tags: c++, ns2

I am working on ns2.35 but i want to access a variable from a program connector.cc 
    #include "packet.h"
    #include "connector.h"

```
int attacker = 0;

static class ConnectorClass : public TclClass {
```

to aodv.cc

```
#include <connector.h>
extern int attacker;
```

then

```
if (malicious == 1000){
  printf("\nDROPD\n");
drop(p, DROP_RTR_ROUTE_LOOP);
}

printf("\nAttacker: %d\n", &attacker);
```

For example i declared a variable int attacker = 0; in connector.cc and i want to access this variable in aodv.cc 
How can i do that? I am not able to do so using the above code. I am using c++.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Not sure why but this question feels wrong to me.

Comment: Do you really mean another *program* or from another *source-file* in the same program? If it's the latter, then search for and read about the `extern` keyword and how to use it in declarations.

Comment: "Compilation unit" I think is the correct term.

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm sure you're thinking about [*translation* unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)? :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you're right, I knew it was some kind of unit :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, variable linkage is internal by default.

This means that you can't get access to a variable in a different translation unit by declaring it `extern` where you want to use it.
If you want to access the variable, it must have been declared `extern` in the translation unit that defines it.

The most common way of accomplishing this is to add the `extern` declaration (but not any definition) to a header and include that both where the variable is used and where it is defined.

(And your `printf` is wrong - you shouldn't use the address-of operator when printing an `int`.)